# Group by data type - 1 table or many tables?

Tags: tables, data-tables

So, I have a table that I want to group by (feature) 3 dimensions (Customer, Vendors, and Route)

Solution 1: As normal practice, I just designed 'a group by feature' on the top of the head of the table with 3 dimensions, so that user could freely group by depend on their situation.

Solution 2: However, one of my teammate suggested that we should divide into 3 tables (it means we did group by for them and divide into 3 tables with 3 dimensions; and each table is located in each tab)

Even though I feel a bit weird about the solution 2, but I do not have any strong reason to deny it. Because in his opinion, it saves user's time, they just switch tabs instead of applying the group by

I am so confused. What do you guys think?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Tien! For me, this is a question about the use cases you need to support, which means you will have to research more on them, and describe more in this question for us to be able to answer. From a very generic point of view, I do not think that users will expect that the same content is spread across different tabs (which require people to look at all three tabs to verify it's actually identical situation). In fact, that's what "group-by" features were invented for, and in the absence of information to the contrary (see above) I would stick to them.

Comment: Make both available and see what more people use. So there'd be 4 tabs, the default tab is Solution #1. Tabs 2, 3, and 4 are grouped Customers, Vendors, and Routes, respectively. Track what gets used more, the "Group by Feature" or whether most users are clicking tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [grouping](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping) and [advanced grouping](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-multiple-groups/groups-aggregates) functionalities of other products?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [*Treegrid*](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/treegrid/examples/treegrid-1/) suits your needs:

> A treegrid widget presents a hierarchical data grid consisting of tabular information that is editable or interactive. Any row in the hierarchy may have child rows, and rows with children may be expanded or collapsed to show or hide the children.

With groups at the top level and the groups' items one level below. (Though this would lead to increased vertical scrolling compared to the tab variant.)

| From CodePen on the example page |
| --- |
| [image: Treegrid - CodePen] |